# Issue when implementing getter and setter from an interface

Tags: vba, object

I have a class which implements another object.  I set a property function for each property of the implemented object but keep getting an 'Invalid use of property' error.  Here's my code:

Test Sub:

```
Sub tst()

Dim a As Derived

Set a = New Derived

a.Base_name = "ALGO" 'Error happens when this executes
End Sub
```

Derived class module:

```
Option Explicit
Implements Base
Private sec As Base
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sec = New Base
End Sub
Public Property Get Base_name() As String
    Call sec.name
End Property
Public Property Let Base_name(value As String)
    Call sec.name(value) 'Error happens here
End Property
```

Base Class module:

```
Private pname As String

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pname
End Property
Public Property Let name(value As String)
    pname = value
End Property
```

Comment: The error for me happens on "Private sec As Base".  You should call the Let instead of assigning "ALGO" to the getter, no? Try a.Base_name("ALGO"). Btw, what is Derived?

Comment: I am calling the let, if i do a.Base_name("ALGO") i was getting an invalid use of property before the sub will even run.  Derived is a class that inherits the base class.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you please edit your post including Base?

Comment: I added in the base.  How do I access and set the name of sec from a?  I get errors when I try the way stated above and the way you suggest in your first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Module1

```
Sub tst()

Dim a As Derived

Set a = New Derived

Debug.Print a.Base_name
a.Base_name = "ALGO"
Debug.Print a.Base_name
End Sub
```

Base Class Module

```
Private pname As String

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pname
End Property
Public Property Let name(value As String)
    pname = value
End Property
```

Derived Class Module

```
Option Explicit
Implements Base
Private sec As Base
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sec = New Base
End Sub
Public Property Get Base_name() As String
    Base_name = sec.name
End Property
Public Property Let Base_name(value As String)
    sec.name = value
End Property
```

Comment: awesome i see that i wasn't returning anything for the get functions in the derived class.  I understand how to properly use it now.  Thanks!